# How to access node attributes and recipe variables in ruby_block

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

New to chef development :), the variable value from an attribute does not seem to be visible in the ruby block.

```
installer = node['jdk']['installer']

ruby_block "tar-folder-name" do
        block do
                command = 'tar -tvf /tmp/#{installer}.tar.gz | head -1 | awk \'{print $NF}\''
                command_out = shell_out(command)
                node.default['tar_folder'] = command_out.stdout
        end
        action :run
end
```

It works when I hardcode the variable value:

```
command = 'tar -tvf /tmp/jdk-7u85-linux-x64.tar.gz | head -1 | awk \'{print $NF}\''
```

How can I use the node attributes in the ruby_block?
Moreover, how can I use a variable value from a ruby block outside ruby block? For info, when I try to use node.tar_folder, it does not have the value extracted in ruby block.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The attribute set in attributes/default.rb file is default['jdk']['installer'] = 'jdk-7u85-linux-x64'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need double quotes. Single quotes in Ruby do not support the `#{foo}` interpolation syntax.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a lot. How to access the ruby block attribute value outside ruby block for later usage in the recipe? I have tried #{node.default['tar_folder']} but it is empty.

Comment: You are probably running in to compile bs converge issues. Check out https://coderanger.net/two-pass/